# codeigniter database moving to another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to solve this codeigniter issue : i have a database table(Mysql) and i need to move all of it's field contents to another table using Php Codeigniter framework ?

What is the syntax for inserting data from one table to another table that can be use in my model & controller?

I tried playing with these CodeIgniter Active Record queries but still no luck:this but it doesn't work

```
function insert_into()  
{    
$this->db->insert('table1');
$this->db->set('to_column');  
$this->db->select('from_column');
$this->db->from('table2');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get content of first table `tableFrom` and iterate over results to insert them to `tableTo`. You can use this code in your model. Don't forget `$this->load->database();` in your controller or in function.

```
function insert_into() {
    $q = $this->db->get('tableFrom')->result(); // get first table
    foreach($q as $r) { // loop over results
        $this->db->insert('tableTo', $r); // insert each row to another table
    }
}
```

@EDIT

Try this code for your controller:

```
<?php
class fdm extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('table','form_validation'));
        $this->load->helper('url'); // load model
        $this->load->model('cbc','',TRUE);
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('cbc','',TRUE);

        $this->cbc->insert_into();
    } 
}
```

To fix error with duplicate entry for key 1 you might want to truncate first table before you import content from table two. You can do this with:

```
function insert_into() {
    $this->db->truncate('tableTo');
    $q = $this->db->get('tableFrom')->result(); // get first table
    foreach($q as $r) { // loop over results
        $this->db->insert('tableTo', $r); // insert each row to another table
    }
}
```

Or you could update rows instead of inserting new:

```
function insert_into() {
        $q = $this->db->get('tableFrom')->result(); // get first table
        foreach($q as $r) { // loop over results
            $this->db->update('tableTo', $r, array('id' => $r->id)); // insert each row to another table
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you test this one?!

Comment: Do you get any errors? Could you show structure of both tables?

Comment: First, create controller, then in this controller create function, for example `function index()`, in this function load database and model. Create model and paste `insert_into()` function there. Open site: `http://mysite.com/CONTROLLER_NAME/FUNCTION_NAME` or `http://mysite.com/CONTROLLER_NAME` for index.

Comment: i did that Daniel and it responded with white web page

Comment: After you load the page, check your database, if action(moving table to another) was performed. Other pages of your CodeIgniter site work correctly?

Comment: this is my model `class cbc extends CI_Model{

public function __construct()

{

parent::__construct();

}

function insert_into() {
    $q = $this->db->get('table1')->result();
    foreach($q as $r) {
        $this->db->insert('table2', $r);
    }
}


}
?>`

Comment: this is my controller `class fdm extends CI_Controller{
    
    function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
  
  $this->load->library(array('table','form_validation'));

  
  $this->load->helper('url');

  // load model
  $this->load->model('cbc','',TRUE);
                $this->load->database();
}
 function index(){
     $this->load->model('cbc','',TRUE);
     $this->load->database();
 }
}`

Comment: thanks man it work but i got that new database error (**A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '1' for key 1**)**Filename: C:\AppServ\www\News\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330**

Comment: I think it's because of that both tables have row with `id = 1`. You might want to truncate first table before you import second table.

Answer (score 1):

A simple one would be

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM   table2
```

In CI use `query()`

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM   table2");
```

Here is the other way

```
$data = $this->db->select('col1, col2, col3')->get('table2');
if($data->num_rows())
{
    $insert = $this->db->insert('table1', $data->result_array());
}
```

Comment: but this way he will be missing the preparing from active records which helps against sql injection

Comment: Yes he will,therefore i havn't used the active record word in my answer

Comment: I prefer the second way :D