# codeigniter database moving to another table using codeigniter drop drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

this may seem as a duplicate question, but my question is sightly different. I am trying to retrieve data from one table to display in a form via a drop down list of which I have had success in implementing , the only issue is that the retrieval was done as an array, I want to now save the retrieved data in another table. Is it possible? and how to go about it? Thanks in advance:
Some of the referral areas: [codeigniter database moving to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894484/codeigniter-database-moving-to-another-table) by [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894484/codeigniter-database-moving-to-another-table)
Here is my code:controller

```
function insert(){
        $data['content'] = 'back/buses/insert';
        $data['idnos'] = $this->owners_model->selectownerid();
        $this->load->view('include/template_back', $data);
    }       
function insert_bus_info(){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('bus_reg','Bus Registration','required');
            // $this->form_validation->set_rules('idno', 'Identification/Passport No', 'required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('bus_make','Bus Make','required');
            // $this->form_validation->set_rules('bus_model','Bus Model','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_of_seats','Number of Seats','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('bus_chasisno','Chasis Number','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('bus_engineno','Engine Number','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('year_of_manufacture','Year of Manufacture','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('date_of_purchase','Date of Purchase','required');


            if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('include/header_back');
                $this->load->view('back/buses/insert');
                $this->load->view('include/footer_back');
            }
            else
            {

                $bus_reg = $this->input->post('bus_reg');
                $idno = $this->input->post($row['idno']);
                $bus_make = $this->input->post('bus_make');
                $bus_model = $this->input->post('bus_model');
                $no_of_seats = $this->input->post('no_of_seats');
                $bus_chasisno = $this->input->post('bus_chasisno');
                $bus_engineno = $this->input->post('bus_engineno');         
                $year_of_manufacture = $this->input->post('year_of_manufacture');
                $date_of_purchase = $this->input->post('date_of_purchase');

                $this->buses_model->insert_bus($bus_reg,$idno,$bus_make,$bus_model,$no_of_seats,$bus_chasisno,$bus_engineno,$year_of_manufacture,$date_of_purchase);
                // $this->do_upload_form();
                //redirect('buses/ do_upload_form','refresh');
            }
        }
```

Model:

```
function selectownerid(){
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT idno,username FROM owner_details');
        return $query->result_array();
    }    
function buseslist(){
            $query = $this->db->get('bus_details');
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                return $query->result_array();
            } 
        }
        function insert_bus($bus_reg,$idno,$bus_make,$bus_model,$no_of_seats,$bus_chasisno,$bus_engineno,$year_of_manufacture,$date_of_purchase){
            $query = "INSERT INTO bus_details(bus_reg,idno,bus_make,bus_model,no_of_seats,bus_chasisno,bus_engineno,year_of_manufacture,date_of_purchase)
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $this->db->query($query,array($bus_reg,$idno,$bus_make,$bus_model,$no_of_seats,$bus_chasisno,$bus_engineno,$year_of_manufacture,$date_of_purchase));
        }
        function edit_bus($bus_reg){
            $this->db->where('bus_reg',$bus_reg);
            $query=$this->db->get('bus_details');
            return $query->row();
        }
```

View:

```
 <?php echo form_open('buses/insert_bus_info', array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-btns">
                  <a href="#" class="panel-close">&times;</a>
                  <a href="#" class="minimize">&minus;</a>
                </div>
                <h4 class="panel-title">Bus Details</h4>
                <p>Please, Insert the details here below...</p>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body panel-body-nopadding">

                <!--Bus registration-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Bus Registration</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="bus_reg" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <?php echo form_error('bus_reg');?>
                </div>
                <!--IDno-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Identification/Passport No</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select class="form-control mb15" placeholder="Identification/Passport No">
                      <?php foreach($idnos as $row){ 
                         echo '<option value="'.$row['idno'].'">'.$row['username'].'</option>';
                      }
                      ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                  <?php echo form_error('idno');?>
                </div>
                 <!--Bus Make-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Bus Make</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select class="form-control mb15" id="bus_make" name="bus_make" placeholder="Bus Make">
                      <option value="">All Buses</option>
                      <option value="Isuzu">Isuzu</option>
                      <option value="Nissan Diesel">Nissan Diesel</option>
                      <option value="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
                      <option value="Hino">Hino</option>
                    </select>
                    <!-- <input type="text"  class="form-control" /> -->
                  </div>
                  <?php echo form_error('bus_make');?>
                </div>
                <!--Bus Model-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Bus Model</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select class="form-control mb15" id="bus_model" name="bus_model" placeholder="Bus Model">
                       <option></option>                       
                    </select>
                    <!-- <input type="text" name="bus_model" class="form-control" /> -->
                  </div>
                  <?php echo form_error('bus_model');?>
                </div>
                 <span id="optionstore" style="display:none;"></span>
                <!--Middle Name-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Number of Seats</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="no_of_seats" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <?php echo form_error('no_of_seats');?>
                </div>                
                <!--Owner Address-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Bus Chasis Number:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="bus_chasisno" class="form-control" />
                    <?php echo form_error('bus_chasisno');?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--Owner Email-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Bus Engine Number:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="bus_engineno" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <?php echo form_error('bus_engineno');?>
                </div>
                <!--Owner Phone Number-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Year of Manufacture</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="year_of_manufacture" id="yearpicker" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <?php echo form_error('year_of_manufacture');?>
                </div>
                <!--Owner place of Residence-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Date of Purchase</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="date_of_purchase" id="datepicker" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <?php echo form_error('date_of_purchase');?>
                </div>
               </div><!-- panel-body -->
              <div class="panel-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
              </div><!-- panel-footer -->
            </div><!-- panel-default -->
          <?php form_close();?>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: When do you want to insert this data to another table? Here `// $this->do_upload_form();`?

Comment: sorry about that the `//$this->do_upload_form();` I was working on another angle for later. But once the data is entered, it should be inserted into the database...

Answer (score 0):

I had found an error or rather something in my view code... Particularly this part

```
<!--IDno-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Identification/Passport No</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select class="form-control mb15" placeholder="Identification/Passport No">
                      <?php foreach($idnos as $row){ 
                         echo '<option value="'.$row['idno'].'">'.$row['username'].'</option>';
                      }
                      ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                  <?php echo form_error('idno');?>
                </div>
```

That is how it looked like but on this line,

```
<select class="form-control mb15" placeholder="Identification/Passport No">
```

this how it should look like

```
<select class="form-control mb15" name="idno" placeholder="Identification/Passport No">
```

It missed **name="idno"**...
It inserts in the database easily... thanks for all your help @Lajos Arjad and @Daniel