# Codeigniter: Move one row from one table to another at one time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm kinda stuck here! I have to two tables `free_members` and `domstic_members` and I need to move selected rows from `free_members` tables to the `domestic_members` table. why I'm saying selected rows because of I at the end of every row in `free_members` tables there is an upgrade option which will move that row to the `domestic_members` table. I have the code but it's not working the way I want. right now what is happening is when I click on upgrade option it just copies the whole table records and sends it's to the other table. this here is the code

#### Controller

```
function upgradeprofile() {
    //  $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('freemember_model');

    $this->freemember_model->upgrade();
}
```

#### model

```
function upgrade() {
    $query = $this->db->get('free_members');
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $this->db->where('id', $member_id);
        $this->db->insert('domestic_members', $row);
    }
}
```

View

```
<center>  Search Member:
                    <input type="text" name ='search' id='search' placeholder="Search a member"/></center>
                    <input type="hidden" name ='limit_from' id='limit_from'/>
                    </form>
<br><center><button type="button" onclick="CallPrint1('background12')">Print</button>
                <div id="background12" class="box-body">
                  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Sr#</th>
                        <th><center>Full Name</th>


                        <th><center>Mobile Number</th>
                         <th><center>Membership# / CNIC</th>
                        <th><center>Email Address</th>

                        <th><center>Province</th>
                        <th><center>District</th>
                        <th><center>Tehsil</th>
                        <th><center>Union Council</th>
<?php /*?>  <?php if($sessiondata['deletemembers']):?><?php */?>
     <?php if($sessiondata['username'] != 'bilal.sabir'):?>
                        <th><center>Delete</th>
  <?php endif;?>

    <?php /*?><?php if($sessiondata['data_modification'] && $sessiondata['username'] != 'bilal.sabir' ):?><?php */?>
         <?php if($sessiondata['username'] != 'bilal.sabir'):?>
                        <th><center>Print</th>
                        <th><center>Edit</th>
                        <th><center>Change Pwd</th>
                        <th><center>Upgrade</th>
    <?php endif;?>


                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php $sr=0;?>
                      <?php foreach ($freemembers as $member): ?>
<tr><td><center><?php echo $sr+=1; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->first_name; ?></td>
<td><center><?php echo $member->mobile; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->cnic; ?></td>
<td><center><?php echo $member->email; ?></td>
<td><center><?php echo $member->province; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->district; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->tehsil; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->uc; ?></td>
<?php /*?> <?php if($sessiondata['deletemembers']):?><?php */?>
     <?php if($sessiondata['username'] != 'bilal.sabir'):?>

<td><center><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/admin/deletefreemember/" . $member->id; ?>">delete</a></td>
<?php endif;?>
  <?php /*?><?php if($sessiondata['data_modification'] && $sessiondata['username'] != 'bilal.sabir' ):?><?php */?>
       <?php if($sessiondata['username'] != 'bilal.sabir'):?>
<td><center><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/admin/printcardfree/" . $member->id; ?>">print</a></td>

<td><center><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/admin/editprofilefree/" . $member->id; ?>">edit</a></td>
<td><center><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/admin/changepasswordfree/" . $member->id; ?>">change pwd</a></td>
<td><center><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/admin/upgradeprofile/" . $member->id; ?>">Upgrade</a></td>
<?php endif;?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

this is the view of my table free_members

[image]

Comment: where is the $member_id in your code ?

Comment: Ok so you are getting all of the free members... and inserting them into the other table... Which is what your code is telling it to do. You have your WHERE in the wrong place. It should be for the get on the free members... But where is $member_id - it will be 0.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw i didn't used this member id in my code!! and yes its moving all my records to the other table!!

Comment: @AnandPandey sir i didn't used this member_id!! can you help me in sorting out this issue? where i can use this member_id in my code?

Comment: @Dawood: Your code is wrong if you want to insert all free members to domestic members than you dont need this line. If you want some selected user than you have to select the free users and insert to domestic users.

Comment: Can you upload your controller and vew.php for particular page?

Comment: @AnandPandey yes sir i need to selected user to add in the dometic user!! and sir let me upload the view code!! and controllers code quite a lengthy one!! sir can i have your email so that i can show you my code properly there? and i can tell you my issue more properly

Comment: If you are not using $this->db->where('id', $member_id); - then why is it in your code? Am I going crazy because I see $member_id in there? You have to use it. But not where you are using it at the moment. Please "Think" about what you are doing.

Comment: You can upload only view.php. I have create my own function for your controller.

Comment: haha yes im not using it right now

Comment: @Dawood - if you insist that you are not using $member_id, then we cannot help you. Plus you "may" have the issue of preserving the member_id from the free table to the "upgrade" table... I do not know why you don't just have a members table and use a field to indicate what level they are - Free or Upgraded or whatever other levels you might have in the future...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw sir basically i changed the code i was doing it in a different way before but now im just trying to move the column. let me change the post then i will let you see where i used that member_id

Comment: @AnandPandey please check my view code

Comment: @Dawood: Its the upgradeprofile() function for only one user will be inserted. Where is the checkbox for select the users in the list?

Comment: There is no checkbox for select multiple users and upgrade to domestic. You should add the checkboxes in each loop and add the memberid in it so when we click on some users for select and send ids of them in upgrade function.

Comment: @AnandPandey can't we just do it without using checkboxes? can we do it using just its id?

Comment: Ok for this you have to add hidden input in the foreach loop :                       <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $member->id ?>" name="allmember[]">

Comment: Your problem is huge and need a lot of modification for this in jquery also so  its not possible here. I will give you the way for this but not all code for you, if you will have any problem than i will assist you.

Comment: @AnandPandey thankyou very much i will let you know if i have problems

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your View, you have this...

```
index.php/admin/upgradeprofile/" . $member->id
```

So if $member->id = 100 the url will be

```
index.php/admin/upgradeprofile/100
```

So you are passing a member_id as mentioned in your model code BUT you are not getting it nor are you using the where correctly.

So you need to get a handle on the member_id...

This is ONE Solution/idea...This relies on you providing a correctly validated integer... You need to always Check/validate your inputs...

**Controller**

```
function upgradeprofile($member_id) {
    // Need to check that $member_id is an integer
    // To be added by the OP

    $this->load->model('freemember_model');

    // $member_id is passed in via the URL.
    $this->freemember_model->upgrade($member_id); 
}
```

**Model**

```
function upgrade() {
    // Which member do we want to get from the free_members Table?
    $this->db->where('id', $member_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('free_members');
    // Did we get a result? i.e was a valid member id passed in?
    if($query !== false) {
        $row = $query->row();
        $this->db->insert('domestic_members', $row);
    } else {
       // Do nothing or handle the case where an illegal number was used...
    }
}
```

Note: This code is not tested and is only to be used as a guide.
It can be refactored a number of ways but I am trying to keep it simple for now.

So please, do not just copy and paste this without at least "thinking" about what you are trying to do and how the code might be written to achieve it.

The main points here are...
1. You have to use a member id of some kind so you can retrieve the record for the free member so you can insert it into the other table.
2. You are providing this "member id" in the url so you need to extract it.
3. You can do that by either setting it as a parameter in the method being called... Or you can use segments ( look it up ).

So once you have the member id you can fetch the free member entry and insert it into the other table BUT What do you want to happen to the entry in the free members table because that is still going to be there and now you have two copies of the same information... Delete it?

If you need further explanation - ask.

**One last point.**
You should be making sure you fully understand what is you are doing and not just doing it because someone said to or you thought it was a good idea... Have a Good Reason and think of the implications...

Comment: yes sir!! thankyou very much for your sugestion!! i will keep this in my mind!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Codeigniter but MySQL syntax should be this:

`INSERT INTO table1 (table1.row1, table1.row2)
SELECT table2.row1, table2.row2
FROM table2
WHERE PUT_YOUR_CONDITION_IF_NEEDED`

I've found **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894484/codeigniter-database-moving-to-another-table)** for Codeigniter.